# ASP .NET MVC 3 Grid Column Data Type and Sorting

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

My question is if it's possible to format decimal data type in model to have 0.00 formatting view? 
Now I use "TotalSumFormatted" which is string so I cannot sort it as it happens for decimal dataype "TotalSum"...

```
    @grid.GetHtml(
    tableStyle: "grid",
    headerStyle: "head",
    alternatingRowStyle: "alt",
    columns: grid.Columns(
                        grid.Column("ShowTime", "Vuelta"),
                                grid.Column("Visitors", "Espectadores"),
                                     grid.Column("TotalSumFormatted", "Monto")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes there is way, use the `format` parameter of the [Column method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg548109%28v=vs.99%29.aspx)

```
 @grid.GetHtml(
    tableStyle: "grid",
    headerStyle: "head",
    alternatingRowStyle: "alt",
    columns: grid.Columns(
    grid.Column("ShowTime", "Vuelta"),                                
    grid.Column("Visitors", "Espectadores"),
    grid.Column("TotalSum", "Monto", format: (item) => string.Format("{0:0.00}", item.TotalSum))
```